# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tipodecontato' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

Good afternoon folks I'm having problems executing the action of displaying my modal follows the error
https://ibb.co/WtdvbCC

Below is my code

const of modal

```
const [contatoAtualizado, setContatoAtualizado] = useState<IContatos>(dados as IContatos);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(dados !== undefined){
      setContatoAtualizado(dados)
    }
  }, [dados, contatoAtualizado]);
```

const para abrir a modal

```
const handleOpen = () => {    
    setOpen(true);
  };
```

button open a modal

```
<Button
          color="primary"
          startIcon={<Icon fontSize="small">add_circle</Icon>}
          onClick={handleOpen}
        >
          Adicionar registro
        </Button>
```

modal

```
<Dialog fullWidth open={true}>
      <DialogTitle>Adicionar profissão</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item lg={6}>
            <Box my={1}>
              <FormLabel
                htmlFor="tipodecontato"
                children={"Tipo de contato"}
                required={true}
              />
              <Select
                fullWidth
                id="tipodecontato"
                name="tipodecontato"
                variant="outlined"
                value={contatoAtualizado.tipodecontato}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setContatoAtualizado({
                    ...contatoAtualizado,
                    tipodecontato: e.target.value as string,
                  })
                }
              >
                {tipodeContato.map((item, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} value={item.name}>
                    {item.name}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item lg={6}>
            <Box my={1}>
              <FormLabel
                htmlFor="informacaoProfissional"
                children={"Informação profissional"}
              />
              <Select
                fullWidth
                id="informacaoProfissional"
                name="informacaoProfissional"
                variant="outlined"
                value={contatoAtualizado.informacaoProfissional}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setContatoAtualizado({
                    ...contatoAtualizado,
                    informacaoProfissional: e.target.value as string,
                  })
                }
              >
                {informacaoProfissional.map((item, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} value={item.name}>
                    {item.name}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item lg={12}>
            <Box my={1}>
              <FormLabel
                htmlFor="contato"
                children={"Contato"}
                required={true}
              />
              <TextField
                required
                fullWidth
                id="contato"
                name="contato"
                placeholder="Digite aqui"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="none"
                value={contatoAtualizado.contato}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setContatoAtualizado({
                    ...contatoAtualizado,
                    contato: e.target.value,
                  });
                }}
              />
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item lg={12}>
            <Box my={1}>
              <FormLabel htmlFor="observacao" children={"Observação"} />
              <TextField
                required
                fullWidth
                placeholder="Digite aqui"
                id="observacao"
                name="observacao"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="none"
                value={contatoAtualizado.observacao}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setContatoAtualizado({
                    ...contatoAtualizado,
                    observacao: e.target.value,
                  });
                }}
              />
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={onClose}>
          Cancelar
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => {
            onSave(contatoAtualizado);
            //console.log(contatoAtualizado)
          }}
        >
          Confirmar
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
```

in this case I'm importing the modal to another component and opening it through the other component

Comment: It looks like in the `onChange` function for the `<select>` element you're referencing the object property `tipodecontato` (not in camel-case) – is this a typo? If you change it to `tipodeContato` does it work?

Comment: thanks for your help, but i solved this issue